# how to trigger a print request to clients machine using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here in, I have nested divs..in which images generate dynamically ...this is the html code ..my problem is if i click the print button the corresponding image need to be printed.

```
    <div id="outputTemp" style="display:none">
    <div id="rightoutputimgae">
    <div id="rightimgId" class="rightimg"  rel="tooltip" content="
     <img src='jqe13/image/1.jpg' class='tooltip-image'/> ">
    <div id="outputimageId" class="outputimage">
       <img src="jqe13/image/1.jpg" alt="Right Bottom Image"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
     <li id="outcheckbox"><input name="outCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
    <li id="outedit">
      <a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/edit_s.PNG" alt="edit" title="Edit">
      </a></li>
    <li id="outdelete"><a href="#" onclick="deleteImg(div11)">
    <img src="jqe13/image/delet_c.PNG" alt="delete" title="Delete"></a></li>
    <li id="outfullscreen">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" alt="Full Screen" class="fullscreen" 
      title="Full Screen"></a></li>
     <li id="outshare">
     <a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/share_c.PNG" alt="Share" title="Share"></a>
     <div id="menu">
     <div id="tooltip_menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu_top" id="email">
    <img src="jqe13/image/email.PNG" alt="Email" title="Email"></a>
    <a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()" class="facebook"><img src="jqe13/image/fb.PNG" 
    alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" id="twitter">
    <img src="jqe13/image/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_bottom" id="save">
     <img src="jqe13/image/save.PNG" alt="Save" title="Save"></a>
     </div>
     </div>
     </li>
     <li id="outprint"><a href="#">
     <img src="jqe13/image/print.PNG" class="printMe" alt="Print" title="Print"></a>
       </li>
     </ul>
      </div>
```

i need to print the image when i click the print button..
    and also i need to print all the images by clicking all button which i need to 
    create later..

`Javascript`

```
    $('.printMe').click(function() {  
    window.print();  
    return false;  
    });
```

does this work for me..can anyone help me with this..

Comment: "does this work for me" did you try it? also, you have a `*` behind `$(...`, that would cause an error, remove it.

Comment: i've read windows.print() prints the whole web page..

Comment: yes, `window.print()` will bring up the print dialogue, just as if you were to push ctrl + p

Comment: how to print only the corresponding image if i click the print button? can you help

Comment: posted solution as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open new window and load only picture there. after that you trigger window.print in it.

If that is the way you are going, I would create simple page that will simplify it

Name it printImage.html, and use something like the following markup

```
<html>
<script>
function onload() {
       var url = window.location.search.substring(1)
       var img = document.getElementById('img')
       img.src = url
       window.print()
}

</script>
<body onload="onload()">
<img href="" id='img' />
</body>
</html>
```

having that you'll be able to new window for image like `printImage.html?myfullpathtotheeimage.jpg`

Actually 2nd option offered by @kennypu is quite simple to implement

add the following stylesheet to your page

```
@media print {
  * { display:none; }
  .print { display:block }
}
```

then just toggle `print` class to the element you are going to print.

Comment: can i achieve it in the same web page, if i click the print button..it should trigger the printer

Comment: then 2nd option offered by @kennypu is only thing i can think of.

Comment: @anuu I don't really get what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print only the corresponding image, you have two choices.

1. When the button is clicked, go to a different page which contains only the image to be printed, and run `window.print()` there.
2. make a print style sheet using the media query: `@media print` and hide everything but the image to be printed in the stylesheet

Comment: write a css and link to the div? is it what u said

Comment: here's a guide on print stylesheets: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: do i use functions to achieve the first one??